# Adapt beginner C# SQL Server INSERT example to work with my database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, database

I have read TONS of tutorials, articles and whatever regarding my issue and honestly, due to my lack of experience I can't twist my fingers around this one so I hope some of you guys can help me out :)

I am working on a project (simply to learn how to program so it's probably very basic), but I have this "News" page where I can update and delete data using a `GridView`.

Now I would like to INSERT something into my database using 3 textboxes and 1 submit button.

I have 3 rows that has to be inserted:

1. Headline
2. Date
3. Content/the news itself.

Which are stored under NyhedTB from the connectionstring: BoligStjernenConnectionString

My query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO [NyhedTB] ([NyhedDato], [NyhedTitel], [NyhedTekst])
VALUES (@NyhedDato, @NyhedTitel, @NyhedTekst)
```

I read on the internet that this code should do the magic for me (I will have to insert my own values ofc.):

```
static void Insert()
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString =
            "server=.;" +
            "initial catalog=employee;" +
            "user id=sa;" +
            "password=sa123";
        using (SqlConnection conn =
            new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd =
                new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails VALUES(" +
                    "@Id, @Name, @Address)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Amal Hashim");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", "Bangalore");

                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //rows number of record got inserted
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //Log exception
        //Display Error message
    }
}
```

I looked at this code and thought it should be easy enough but really, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Oh it's C#! Sorry I'll edit my post.

Comment: Do You get any error? If your code gets into 'catch' part, what is exception message? If not, what is 'rows' value after ExecutoNonQuery?

Comment: ... and, what is your question?

Comment: So if you substitute your query with the one in the code sample, what happens?

Comment: Well guys I'm not even that far into it yet. I'm not sure how to write the code-behind and/or edit the example code I gave so it works with my project. - again, it's all because of my lack of knowledge :)

Comment: Just change the Sql connectinn string/Sql query and add the params as per your code. That's what you need to change in the above code to get it work.

Comment: Okay I've changed the code so I, believe it fits mine:

Comment: To get example working with your project we need to know a lot about your project or at least what parts of example have You left unchanged. I suggest You become familiar with debugging techniques first, debug your program and then come back with question. Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt(v=VS.90).aspx or http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: ah I can't put a new answer up to my question due to less reputation. - I have changed the code-behind so it have the values from my database. But one of my main-issuses is that I don't know how to tell my 3 textboxes and 1 button that "This data should be inserted into the database", one thing is having the code-behind working but how to make the buttons and textboxes workign is still a misery.

Comment: @MikeBertelsen is this C# WinForms (windows app) or is it ASP.Net (website)? Can oyu edit your Question and add the relevant tag.

Comment: AH It's working!! I ran though all of these comments and really, I learned a lot from them! My problem was first of all, my "NyhedaDate" as a "Datetime" in my Database so I changed it to "varchar" and wolla! It worked!
I learned about click events, where to put the code-behind, how to connect to my database AND Insert!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is some advice to get you going, learning programming is a lot of
>   trial and error.

1. Start off basic, litrally put three textboxes on a form/page and a
   button.
2. Double click the button to go the code-behind and view the buttons
   click event.
3. Paste in the body of code included with your question (everything in the try-catch).
4. Put a break-point on the Public Void Button_Click line of code and press F11 to
   step through the code.

> "one thing is having the code-behind working but how to make the buttons and textboxes working is still a misery"*

Put the textbox as the value rather than your hardcoded values:

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", textBox1.Text);

You also should not insert the Id value, instead modify the EmployeeDetails table and set the ID column to in the properties set Identity Specification (IS Identity) = True. Then right click the ID column and set Primary Key.

Post any error messages you encounter here and when you do get get it working, an additional exercise (that will be very valuable for you) would use a database stored procedure rather than ad-hoc SQL, to safe-guard against sql-injection attacks.

*I'm assuming you have SQL Server installed and have a 'employee' database with a table called EmployeeDetails.*

Comment: Hey! (btw you already helped me here because I didn't know the code was supposed to be in the Button code-behind!) I did as you said buddy and I think I found something (if I'm doing this right hehe). I see a red text under Autos when the debugger comes to my: connection string: string connectionString = "server=PCM12443\\SQLEXPRESS;" + "initial catalog=BoligStjernen;" + "user id=sa;" + "password=rozweba"; -- But nothing seems to be inserted into the database. I do not have the Northwind database installed, I just change the values to what is inside my own database :)

Comment: Keep pressing F11 to step through the code, when something is wrong you'll see an Exception with the details. What happens when you F11 over the conn.Open(); line of code? If it fails 1st make sure your connection string is correct, make a text file (a.txt) rename the extension to udl (a.udl) -> connect to your database, when you can  connect successfully from the Data Link Properties window, rename the file back to a.txt and everything after "Provider=SQLNCLI.1;"  is the correct connection string.

Comment: The only place the "Exception" or "Red icon" appears is just right after Catch (SqlException ex) where it says: {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (and lots more code I can't enter due to too long message)

Comment: @MikeBertelsen -The best advice I can give you is to pick up a beginner book on ASP.Net programming. Mate, we've all been there at one stage and that way atleast you start off on the right foot - to make it easier to piece together such a complex fusion of math, science, art & technology.

Comment: just use a calendar control for the date mate:)

Comment: Cheers Jeremy.. Well, yeah I suppose you are right. I just don't understand how you guys can work with this everyday, my head is already melting! But honestly I am more than suprised to see how many people have given replies to my post, it's a little confusing to keep track of them all but very much appreciated!:) Not to go off-topic but can u recommend a book?

Comment: @Mike: Check the Resources part of the [description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) of the C# tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void GvManualShows_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //label lbl = (label)e.Row.FindControl("lblHidden");
        if (e.Row.Cells[14].Text == "Y")
        {
            // CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chk");

            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkBox");
            chk.Checked = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple. You just have to modify the connection string, the query and its parameters:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString =
            "server=SQLServer;" +         // SQLServer is your SQL server machine
            "initial catalog=employee;" + // employee is your database
            "user id=sa;" +               // sa is the login to connect the database
            "password=sa123";             // sa123 is the password of the login
        using (SqlConnection conn =
            new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO [NyhedTB] ([NyhedDato], [NyhedTitel], [NyhedTekst]) " +
                "VALUES (@NyhedDato, @NyhedTitel, @NyhedTekst)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NyhedDato", textBoxDate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NyhedTitel", textBoxTitle.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NyhedTekst", textBoxBody.Text);

                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // Inserted rows number
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //Log exception
        //Display Error message
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Otiel! Hehe, yeah it's fairly simple if you know how to, but thanks for the provided code. I think that's how I did it aswell, but as it seems to be working without any issues I was wondering how I tell my button that the values in my 3 textboxes should be inserted into the database? I can't seem to find any indication that the current code-behind is searching for any textboxes? (again, lack of knowledge :))

Comment: @MikeBertelsen: Ok. See my edited answer. To get the value of a `textBox`, use the [`TextBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx) property. To execute the code when your button is clicked, use the [click event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx).

Comment: Ah, I already learned something new here, I didn't know it was called a click event... But when I click my Button the page flashes white quickly and thats about it. I believe (though I'm not certainly sure) that my issuse is the server in my connectionstring. Because I have done everything else you experts have recommended.

Comment: AH It's working!! I ran though all of these comments and really, I learned a lot from them! My problem was first of all, my "NyhedaDate" as a "Datetime" in my Database so I changed it to "varchar" and wolla! It worked!
I learned about click events, where to put the code-behind, how to connect to my database AND Insert!

Answer (score 0):

I made changed example code with your requirements and added comments, hope it would be a bit clearer for you to understand whats going on:

```
static void Insert()
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString =
        "server=.;" +
        "initial catalog=MyDatabaseName;" + //here you write database name where your NyhedTB table is
        "user id=sa;" + //user name to connect to database
        "password=sa123"; //password
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd =
              new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO NyhedTB (NyhedDato, NyhedTitel, NyhedTekst) VALUES (@NyhedDato, @NyhedTitel, @NyhedTekst)", conn))
            {
                //all "things" in your sql command what beggins with @ 
                //means that it is parameter and you need to pass values for these parameters: 
                //For @NyhedDato parameter you set text from your textbox
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NyhedDato", txtDate.Text);

                //For @NyhedTitel parameter you set text from title textbox
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NyhedTitel", txtTitle.Text);

                //For @NyhedTekst parameter you set text from content textbox
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NyhedTekst", txtContent.Text);

                //Execute insert command and get how many records was efected, in this case it should be rows = 1 because you inserting just one record
                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
       //Log exception
       //Display Error message
    }
}
```

P.s. code not tested. And when you say

> I have 3 rows that has to be inserted:
>   Headline
>   Date
>   Content/the news itself.

actually you mean you want to insert `record` with `fields`

Comment: Yes sir, I suppose that's what I mean haha.. Let me try and explain myself again just in case. I have 3 textboxes (headline, date, content) and a button.. When I enter values into these 3 textboxes and hit the button, I want them to be inserted into my database and displayed on my News page (I can already display the content).