# How to store the time in a database in another form?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, database-connection

How do i store the value in "ShowTime" in a database? This should be in form2 that has the connection to the database. And the code below belongs in form1. I have created the database and a table.

This is supposed to be a highscore-list that stores the top 10 highscores.

I have created a datagridview in from2 and tried to automaticly get the "ShowTime"-value in under a column named "time" without success. Sadly i deleted this code and tried to use a label instead but also here i havent managed to solve my problem. I really dont have any code to show how i tried because i dont know what is the proper way to do this.

```
private Stopwatch _sw = new Stopwatch();

public void StartGame()
{
    ...
    _sw.Start();
}

GameOver()
{
    _sw.Stop();
    ShowTime = String.Format("Congratulation, you won the game in: {0} seconds.",    _sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
```

Comment: The same way you'd store any other double.

Comment: I'm perplexed...the variable `ShowTime` is a string, which you would store as a varchar, right?  Or if you're talking about a timespan, then why not use a Time type in sql?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you believe this SO post

[What is the correct SQL type to store a .Net Timespan with values > 24:00:00?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000)

You use a bigint.

Of course, that is based on values > 24 hours, which seems overkill in your situation.

I would probably go with a simple Sql `Float`

I'm not too happy with the formatting (in the POST, not the code itself), but have a look at this simple example for connecting to a database and updating a value.

[Adapt beginner C# SQL Server INSERT example to work with my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224371/adapt-beginner-c-sharp-sql-server-insert-example-to-work-with-my-database)

Comment: I have never been doing any connection to a database before so this is my first try :) so i would really appriciate if you could explain this further? I have the value, but all i need is to store it and automaticly shows in a label or a datagridview which i havent made work.

Comment: Edited with a link that might help.